# group of checkboxes to check/uncheck checkboxes in listview form

Tags: vb.net, listview, checkbox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWpAb.jpg)I am new to Visual Basic. I am using Microsoft Visual Basic 2008 and I am also new to programming. Can anyone help me with this? I am trying to figure out how to check or uncheck the checkboxes in the listview form. The values in the listview are from a databse. I used MySql phpmyadmin in creating the database though. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Research the ListViewItem.Checked property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.checked(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Okay I'll check the web site. Thanks bro